# How can i get a list of modules

Tags: module, prism, autofac

I have a WPF application built on top of PRISM.
When i tries to list module before loaded modules when find modules,I use dicitonary find module,but i dont look any module in modulecategory.

Any suggestions on how I can do this?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is to name your module assemblies in a special way, like `MySomething.module.dll` and then look for these when putting together the module catalog. There once was a module catalog implementation around on codeplex that allowed to pass a search pattern including subfolders... [link](https://archive.codeplex.com/?p=prismextensions)

Comment: I had known it,because  shell  init before    bootstraper's run   in prism ,so i didn't look module in modulecategory.Thank you.